# Searchkick Order by price Or Name returns incorrect order of results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, spree, searchkick

I'm using searchkick to for searching and ordering products on my rails application everything is working fine except

```
search("*", order: { price: {order: :desc}}
// or
search("*", order: { price: :desc})
// name
search("*", order: { name: {order: :desc}}
//or
search("*", order: { name: :desc})
```

both of the above return correct results but with incorrect order

my price & name mapping is

```
"name"=>
      {"type"=>"keyword",
       "fields"=>{"analyzed"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_index"}, "word_start"=>{"type"=>"text", "analyzer"=>"searchkick_word_start_index"}},
       "ignore_above"=>30000},
     "price"=>{"type"=>"float"}
```

How can i fix this so i get correct order of results ?! i.e by price desc ?

Comment: Are you sure the price is stored in Order model ? It should be tracked in the LineItem.

Comment: The price is in product model, order is for sorting results

Comment: Do you use Spree ?

Comment: yes i do, spree 3.1

Comment: In Spree, the price of ordered items ared stored in LineItem which belongs to Order: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/c6728170d89b47c127da6f211084743f885336f7/core/app/models/spree/line_item.rb#L6

Comment: I didn't mention LineItem, I want to search for products and order them by name or price .

Answer (score 3):

You can try to debug what's going on with:

```
Model.search("*", order: {price: :desc}, debug: true)
```

And

```
Model.search("*", order: {price: :desc}, explain: true).response
```

[Source](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#debugging-queries)

Once possibility is your search index is not in sync with your database. Try doing a full reindex (`Model.reindex`) to see if that fixes it.